# jquery, animation is not working correctly with the using of .off() and .on() for div

Tags: jquery, animation, html

to the purpose.
i have form with 3 div, when you hover over them, will go animation. all is good. when you click one of the div (click1,click2,click3),it becomes inactive by means of .off().(I using to activate .on()) Here begins a problem. when you click on all div(cyclically or fast) , animation is not working correctly. the code you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/46Uj4/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#home').click(home = function(h) {          
        if(h.which === 1) {

            $("#home").animate({
                left: '25px'
            });
            $("#home").css({
                'background': '#000000',
                'color' : 'whitesmoke' 
            });    
            $("#home" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                });   
            $("#portfolio,#info" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'35px'
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                });
            $("#portfolio,#info").css({
                'background': 'purple',
                'color' : 'darkviolet' 
            });
            $('#current').text('text1');
            $("#home").off('click');  
            $("#portfolio").on('click', portfolio);     
            $('#info').on('click', info); 
        }          
    });

    $('#portfolio').click(portfolio = function(p) {        
        if(p.which === 1) {

            $("#portfolio").animate({
                left: '25px'
            });
            $("#portfolio").css({
                'background': '#000000',
                'color' : 'whitesmoke' 
            });    
            $("#portfolio" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                });     
            $("#home,#info" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'35px'
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                }); 
            $("#home,#info").css({
                'background': 'purple',
                'color' : 'darkviolet' 
            });
            $('#current').text('text2');
            $("#home").on('click', home);  
            $("#portfolio").off('click');     
            $('#info').on('click', info);
        }              
    });   

    $('#info').click(info = function(i) {        
        if(i.which === 1) {

            $("#info").animate({
                left: '25px'
            });
            $("#info").css({
                'background': '#000000',
                'color' : 'whitesmoke' 
            });    
            $("#info" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                });      
            $("#home,#portfolio" ).hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'35px'
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    $(this).css({
                        'left':'25px'
                    });
                });
                $("#home,#portfolio").css({
                'background': 'purple',
                'color' : 'darkviolet' 
            });
            $('#current').text('text3'); 
            $("#home").on('click', home);  
            $("#portfolio").on('click', portfolio);     
            $('#info').off('click'); 
        }            
    });
});
```

Who knows, what's the problem?

Answer (score -2):

`.off()` has to match `.on()` exactly, so where you have `$("#home").on('click', home);`, you need to use `$("#home").off('click', home);` instead of `$("#home").off('click');`

I'm not sure if that fixes your issue or not.

To clarify: I'm not saying to call .on() and .off() in the same function. I'm just saying that when you call .off(), the same parameters need to be used when you called .on().

Comment: Why call a function 'home', if $ ("# home"). off ('click'), is located in the same function?

Comment: Not in the same function. Wherever you have .off('click'), you need to replace it with .off('click', whateveryouusedintheonfunctionhere)

It needs to match the .on function exactly to work.

Maybe this will help: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: i need to that when you click on the div, it became inactive, therefore, i using .off and on =) but there's a problem =) and in your code, too (when you click quickly or cyclically)

Comment: adding '.stop(true,true)' prior to executing '.addClass()' or '.removeClass()' cures that: http://jsfiddle.net/46Uj4/4/